# Java exception in tool installation under linux OS

Tags: java, linux, unix, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install one tool under linux and getting java exception for same, could some one help me in this case.

java -version
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)

sudo ./automation.bin 
Preparing to install...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...

Invocation of this Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)

Stack Trace:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
        at java.awt.Window.initGC(Window.java:475)
        at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:495)
        at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:537)
        at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)
        at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:385)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.g(DashoA8113)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.h(DashoA8113)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA8113)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(DashoA8113)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA8113)
        at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA8113)
This Application has Unexpectedly Quit: Invocation of this Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)

Do i need to set any variable in my linux machine or do I initiated wrong way to install tool. Please assist me.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed,

Usally in these cases , simply rename the file or ftp properly.
If java version is correct in server, then issue is related to file, sometimes file is corrupted. I renamed file in generic version and performed it is installed, + 1 command:

for installation use console way:

./filename.bin -i console